MDC context erasing if Spring JDBC repository injected
I'm in stuck with reactive spring.
I want to add otel tracing to my kotlin with spring WebFlux project. All works fine until I inject spring-data-jdbc repository. When I inject non-reactive repository my MDC is always null. When I change spring-data-jdbc to spring-data-r2dbc mdc context works fine.
Why Spring WebFlux has this behaviour?
This code prints null:
@RestController
class TestController(
    private val repository: MyJDBCCrudRepository,
) {
    
    @GetMapping("/api/public/v1/hello")
    suspend fun publicRoute() = withContext(MDCContext()) {
        val mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
        println(mdc) // print null
    }
}

This code works fine:
@RestController
class TestController(
    private val repository: MyR2DBCCrudRepository,
) {
    
    @GetMapping("/api/public/v1/hello")
    suspend fun publicRoute() = withContext(MDCContext()) {
        val mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
        println(mdc) // print correct context
    }
}

My dependencies:
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
// uncomment for r2dbc case
//implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc")

// observability
implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel")
implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin")
implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter")
implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-kotlin")

// Kotlin
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:2.0.21")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.9.0")
implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j:1.9.0")

